# undefined element in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Don't quite know how else to phrase this question.

When I do

```
function reverseArray(array) {
  var arr = [];
  for(i = 0; i <= array.length; i++)
    arr.unshift(array[i]);
  return arr;
}
```

And then call it with `console.log(reverseArray(["A", "B", "C"]));` my output is:

`[undefined, "C", "B", "A"]`

But when I subtract 1 from array.length in the for loop like so

```
function reverseArray(array) {
  var arr = [];
  for(i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++)
    arr.unshift(array[i]);
  return arr;
}
```

I get exactly what I expect, which is: `["C", "B", "A"]`

What gives?

Comment: Shout out to the trigger happy downvoter! Your feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Some people downvote questions where the poster does not seem to have done basic debugging of his or her code. In this particular case, all you really needed to do is step through your code and watch it execute. You would have seen it doing the extra iteration which put the `undefined` into the array, and thus solved your problem without having to bother to post to SO or have other people look at your problem. I myself don't usually downvote in such situations, but I don't think it's unreasonable to do so. Learn how to user the debugger, and you will be able to solve many of your own problems.

Comment: I caught the mistake, I just didn't quite understand *why* the array index runs from 0 to length - 1. Is that silly of me? It seemed counterintuitive at the moment, but that's because I just forgot that one rule.

Comment: Well, it's not some special rule you have to remember, it's just, ummm, basic counting. If you want to count three times, starting at 0, then it's 0, 1, 2. And 2 is three minus 1.

Comment: @torazaburo I know, I know. I'm new to programming, and zero-based counting is still new enough for me to have forgotten it. Thanks for tolerating my dum questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because array indexes are from 0 to length - 1, since your loop you are using `i<=array.length` when `i` becomes `array.length` `array[i]` will be undefined.

So in your for loop you need `i=0; i<array.length`

```js
function reverseArray(array) {
  var arr = [];
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    arr.unshift(array[i]);
  return arr;
}
console.log(reverseArray(["A", "B", "C"]));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `array` variable you pass in such as `["A", "B", "C"]` is 3 items long.

Your condition

```
for(i = 0; i <= array.length; i++)
```

will iterate 4 times instead of 3.

When it looks for `array[3]`, there is nothing, so `undefined` is shifted.

Answer (score 1):

Isnt it pretty obvious?? Array index are from 0 to (length - 1). so the last value that you unshift is of array[length]  which exceed the boundary and hence is undefined!

The below jsbin will help you understand

[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/haqove/1/edit?html,js,console)